# ¿Qué es más recomendable para dibujar una imagen con o sin ángulo?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una clase que dibuja una imagen:

```js
class Tile {
    constructor(source){
        this.tile = new Image();
        this.tile.src = source;
    }

    draw(x=0, y=0, width, height){
        ctx.drawImage(this.tile, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, la clase anterior no da la posibilidad de dibujar la imagen con una rotación. El siguiente código puede rotar la imagen perfectamente, no obstante, si el usuario no aporta un ángulo de rotación, este será 0, es decir, la imagen no se verá rotada:

```js
draw(angle=0, x=0, y=0, width, height){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.drawImage(this.tile, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Entiendo que rotar una imagen en 0 puede consumir recursos innecesarios, ya que guardas el estado del *lápiz*, lo trasladas, etc., cuando en realidad puedes limitarte a dibujar la imagen como en la primera clase: `ctx.drawImage(this.tile, x, y, width, height);`

En términos de mejor rendimiento, ¿es mejor crear dos clases, una para cuando el usuario no quiera aplicar una rotación sobre la imagen y otra clase para cuando el usuario si desea establecer una rotación, o simplemente con crear una sola clase y el ángulo a 0 no va a dar problemas de rendimiento?

Comment: Si tienes dudas sobre el rendimiento debes probarlo, no hay más ciencia. Además siempre puedes poner un `if` y usar los 2 métodos

Comment: `draw(angle=0, x=0, y=0, width, height)` -> MAL. Si no quieres pasar `angle` te obliga a poner un 0, no sirve el valor por defecto que le has puesto... `draw( width, height, x=0,y=0, angle=0)` si no quieres pasar ninguno de los 3 últimos parámetros, no tienes por qué ponerlos, para eso está el valor por defecto. Además eso te permite tener un único método y hacer `if (angle) ctx.rotate(angle);`, y ya está, si lo pasas se rota, si no, lo ignora. No hay consumo innecesario de recursos. Y recuerda, los parámetros opcionales van siempre al final! Si no, no son opcionales :)

Comment: Puede ser peor tener 2 clases. No sé si en cuanto a rendimiento. ¿Vas a tener que cargar en memoria ambas?. En cuanto a complejidad... es muy probable. En algún punto vas a necesitar agregar lógica para determinar cual utilizar ya sea para crear o editar.